# question about shading and topology of the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, topology

I have a question about bad shading on a mesh.

I was following this dude's tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOiVIeOxrMU

then as always something happened to me that did not happen in the video

[image]

so there is a slim cut mark running through the mesh which is not intended.

[image: I guess the edge is causing this]

Since it is caused by the edge, if i dissolve this edge, it looks like this
[image: Annoying white mark]

My question is why does this mesh have that subtle white mark all of sudden,
and is there a way to get rid of it?

thanks,

Comment: please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Josh drops bevel modifiers on everything so I'm assuming you have one here. He also has MANY tutorials on how to fix this exact issue.